# .vscode folder missing from Angular2+ project

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I have an Angular2+ project and I need to create launch.json file inside of .vscode folder that is supposed to be immediately under my Angular project folder. I do not see .vscode folder.

I can create it with the command prompt but I wonder why do I not have one in my project when the instructions I am following assume it should be there already?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Figured out the way to do it.

1. In VS Code, click on Debug button:

   [image]
2. In the Debug toolbar on top, click Configure button:

   [image]
3. The popup will appear under VS Code toolbar, asking which debugger you want to use. Select one from the list. Node.js debugger is built into VS Code. I installed Chrome debugger and it shows up in the list.

   [image]

Selecting one of the debuggers creates **.vscode** folder (if it did not exist) and saves the file **launch.json** in it.